# make a div with jquery dialog scroll to bottom when loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#Dialog").dialog({
         title: "dialog",
         width: 360,
         height: 365,
         modal: false,
         resizable: false,
         focus: function (event, ui) {
             $("#ToClientID").val(ToClient); 
         },
         open: function (event, ui) {
             $(this).scrollTop(10000000000000000000000000);
         }
     });


 });
```

why the div isn't scrolling to bottom when he is loaded

Comment: 10000000000000000000000000 exceeds the max int value of javascript

Comment: try changing it to `$(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height());`

Comment: Can you prepare a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is an animation, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Dialog").dialog({
         title: "dialog",
         width: 360,
         height: 365,
         modal: false,
         resizable: false,
         focus: function (event, ui) {
             $("#ToClientID").val(ToClient); 
         },
         open: function (event, ui) {
             $(this).animate({
                 scrollTop: $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()
             });
         }
     });
 });
```